# ListProperty<T> vs. ObjectProperty<ObservableList<T>>

Tags: java, javafx

I noticed that *itemsProperty* in `ListView` is of type `ObjectProperty<ObservableList<T>>`, but I would have expected `ListProperty<T>`.

Now I wonder: When should I Use `ObjectProperty<ObservableList<T>>`, and when `ListProperty<T>`?

Comment: that's a design error, IMO

Comment: As @kleopatra says, the use of `ObjectProperty` instead of a `ListProperty` in the `**List**View` seems like a poor decision. As it is, I always end up adding my own listeners anyway; seems redundant.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer can be found in the JavaFX documentation for [ObjectProperty](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/property/ObjectProperty.html), specifically this line:

> For specialized implementations for ObservableList, ObservableSet and ObservableMap that **also report changes inside the collections**, see ListProperty, SetProperty and MapProperty, respectively.

So using `ObjectProperty<ObservableList<T>>` will report if the `ObservableList` itself changes, but not if any members **within** that `ObservableList` are changed.

So, to answer your question, you would use `ObjectProperty<ObservableList<T>>` when you only need to be reported if the `ObservableList` has changed (ie: items added or deleted). You should use `ListProperty<T>` if you also need to track changes made to the actual items within that `ObservableList`.

Comment: beware: _will report if the ObservableList itself changes_ that's true, with a catch - it fires invalidation events always, but change events only if `!newList.equals(oldList)` The latter is nasty if client code needs to re-wire listeners (as f.i. skins of virtualized controls) - your suggestion to use ListProperty in these contexts is full on :)